# How to validate a .csv file before storage in C#?

Tags: c#, validation, csv, .net

I have some .csv files which I am parsing before storing in database.

I would like to make application more robust, and perform validation upon the .csv files before save in the database.

So I am asking you guys if you have some good links, or code examples, patterns, or advice on how to do this?

I will paste an example of my .csv file below. The different data fields in the .csv file are separated by tabs. Each new row of data is on a new line.

I have been thinking a little about the things I should validate against and came up with the list below (I am very open for other suggestions, in case you have anything which you think should be added to the list?)

```
Correct file encoding.
That file is not empty.
Correct number of lines/columns.
correct number/text/date formats.
correct number ranges.
```

This is how my .csv file looks like (file with two lines, data on one line is separated by tabs).

```
4523424 A123456 GT-P1000    mobile phone    Samsung XSD1234 135354191325234
345353  A134211 A8181   mobile phome    HTC S4112-ad3   111911911932343
```

The string representation of above looks like:

```
"4523424\tA123456\tGT-P1000\tmobile phone\tSamsung\tXSD1234\t135354191325234\r

\n345353\tA134211\tA8181\tmobile phome\tHTC\tS4112-ad3\t111911911932343\r\n"
```

So do you have any good design, links, patterns, code examples, etc. on how to do this in C#?

Comment: What do you want to validate? The structure? If every line contains as many tabs as other lines? Or do you want to validate date? Like minimum and maximum values? Or datatypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do like this:

Create a class to hold each parsed line with expected type

```
 internal sealed class Record {
     public int Field1 { get; set; }
     public DateTime Field2 { get; set; }
     public decimal? PossibleEmptyField3 { get; set; }
     ...
 }
```

Create a method that parses a line into the record

```
public Record ParseRecord(string[] fields) {
    if (fields.Length < SomeLineLength)
        throw new MalformadLineException(...)

    var record = new Record();

    record.Field1 = int.Parse(fields[0], NumberFormat.None, CultureInvoice.InvariantCulture);
    record.Field2 = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[1], "yyyyMMdd", CultureInvoice.InvariantCulture);
    if (fields[2] != "")
        record.PossibleEmptyField3 = decimal.Parse(fields[2]...)

    return record;
}
```

Create a method parsing the entire file

```
public List<Record> ParseStream(Stream stream) {
    var tfp = new TextFileParser(stream);

    ...
    try {
        while (!tfp.EndOfData) {
            records.Add(ParseRecord(tfp.ReadFields());
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException ex) {
        ... // show error
    }
    catch (MalformadLineException ex) {
        ... // show error
    }

    return records;
}
```

And then I create a number of methods validating the fields

```
public void ValidateField2(IEnumerable<Record> records) {
    foreach (var invalidRecord in records.Where(x => x.Field2 < DateTime.Today))
       ... // show error
}
```

I have tried various tools but since the pattern is straight forward they don't help much.
(You should use a tool to split the line into fields)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) a free/open source .Net library to deal with CSV and many other file formats.

Answer (score 0):

adrianm and Nipun Ambastha

Thank you for your response to my question.

I solved my problem by writing a solution to validate my .csv file myself.

It's quite possible a more elegant solution could be made by making use of adrianm's code, but I didn't do that, but I am encouraging to give adrianm's code a look.

I am validating the list below.

- Empty file
  new FileInfo(dto.AbsoluteFileName).Length == 0
- Wrong formatting of file lines.
      string[] items = line.Split('\t');
  if (items.Count() == 20)
- Wrong datatype in line fields.
  int number;
      bool isNumber = int.TryParse(dataRow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), out number);
- Missing required line fields.
  if (dataRow.ItemArray[4].ToString().Length < 1)

To work through the contents of the .csv file I based my code on this code example:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/256797-reading-tab-delimited-file

Comment: I am sorry, but currently I have actually forgotten what this was about. But for myself, the answer I wrote was just the quickest way for myself to solve my problem at the time.

Comment: Am I the only one who can move the accepted answer? As said, currently I have completely forgotten what this is about. So I don't really feel entitled to move the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, you are the owner of the question. Maybe (no one in SO can say yes or not about this) your answer is useful, but it's polite that if someone get a better answer, you set that one as the good one. Also give it to you more "credits". (Sorry for my english)

Comment: Ok I think I changed the accepted answer to the most popular answer.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should take a look to 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

We have been using this in our projects, its quite robust and does what it says.