# Validate a CSV file for not having the separator as part of the data

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a CSV file which need's to be checked for the the separator not being part of the data.

Let's say it has two columns and the separator is a comma.

The header:

```
Column1, Column2
```

and the data like so:

```
data1, data2
data3, data3,3
```

The second row, second column data is invalid as it has a comma in it.
I can read each row and split it based on the separator and check the array length.
In this case if it's greater than 2 the data is invalid.

Is there any other way using LINQ or any external library that can help me here.

Regards.

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608486/how-to-validate-a-csv-file-before-storage-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
 var content = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                content.Add(line);
                line = reader.ReadLine();          //read in all lines

            }
        }
//var content = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.ASCII); //bad practice, see comments
var vaildContent = (from val in content                       //specify source ("content"), create temporary var ("val") for processing
                                where val.Split(new []{","},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length == 2  // condition(s)
                                select val).ToList(); //If condition is true, slect the object
```

will accomplish what you want, even if i see no need for linq. Of cause you can extend this (replacing my hardcoded "2" by a custom value built based on the header of your file).

Comment: Whilst a fine answer, try to avoid .NET functions that don't utilise an iterator such as the case in **string[] File.ReadAllLines()**. They are not terribly efficient if they return a large number of items/large memory sets.   **Directory.GetFiles()** is inefficient also as [stated by Microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MickyDuncan Thanks for pointing this. This is new to me. I will update my answer using a normal streamreader.

Comment: That's better. The other one could lead to duplicate copies. :)

Comment: Or there's `File.ReadLines()` that returns an `IEnumerable<string>` as of .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the header first, count how many columns it's supposed to be. Then for each data, split by comma and take as many columns in the header.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);

// need to check how many lines returned before reaching here
var header = lines.FirstOrDefault();
var count = (header ?? string.Empty).Count(x => x == ',') + 1;
var data = lines
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(x => x
        .Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Take(count)
        .ToArray());
```

**Update** with `StreamReader` instead of `File.ReadLines(path)` and wrap it in a method.

```
static IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCsv(string path)
{
    using (var stream = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        var line = stream.ReadLine();
        if (line != null)
        {
            var count = line.Count(x => x == ',') + 1;
            while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var data = line
                    .Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Take(count)
                    .ToArray();
                yield return data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
IEnumerable<string[]> lines = ReadCsv(path);
```

**Update 2** As suggested by @Juharr, `ReadAllLines` is replaced with `ReadLines` so that the lines can be enumerated before the whole lines are returned.

Comment: Whilst also a fine answer, be aware of using **string[] File.ReadAllLines()** on potentially large files. See my comment on **BudBrot**'s answer

Comment: Or just use `File.ReadLines`.