# LINQ Method - Optimization

Tags: c#, linq, csv, performance-testing

I'm reading a CSV file splitting it into cols, then grouping into a new class.

It looks clunky just wondering is there is a more simple method for instance like not selecting them into the class first:

*EDIT:* so to clarify I'm trying to get the `TimesheetHours` grouped by all the other columns.

```
var rowList = csvFile.Rows.Select(row => row.Split(','))
    .Select(cols => new UtilisationRow {
        UploadId = savedUpload.Id,
        FullName = cols[0],
        TimesheetWorkDateMonthYear = Convert.ToDateTime(cols[1]),
        TimesheetTaskJobnumber = cols[2],
        TimesheetWorktype = cols[3],
        TimesheetHours = Convert.ToDouble(cols[4]),
        TimesheetOverhead = cols[5]
    })
    .GroupBy(d => new {
        d.FullName,
        d.TimesheetWorkDateMonthYear,
        d.TimesheetTaskJobnumber,
        d.TimesheetWorktype,
        d.TimesheetOverhead
    })
    .Select(g => new UtilisationRow {
        FullName = g.First().FullName,
        TimesheetWorkDateMonthYear = g.First().TimesheetWorkDateMonthYear,
        TimesheetTaskJobnumber = g.First().TimesheetTaskJobnumber,
        TimesheetWorktype = g.First().TimesheetWorktype,
        TimesheetHours = g.Sum(s => s.TimesheetHours),
        TimesheetOverhead = g.First().TimesheetOverhead
    })
    .ToList();
```

Many thanks,
Lee.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of the groupby and last select is, are you trying to filter distinct elements? because there are much better ways to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to groupby all cols, and sum the TimesheetHours `TimesheetHours = g.Sum(s => s.TimesheetHours)`

Comment: Use oledb to read into a datatable.  I gave a little example the other day : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788682/validate-content-of-csv-file-c-sharp/48791373#comment84640949_48791373

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two problems in your code are that you call `First()` repeatedly on a group, while you should retrieve that same data from group's key, and that you are using `UtilisationRow` in the first `Select`, which should use an anonymous type instead:

```
var rowList = csvFile.Rows.Select(row => row.Split(','))
    .Select(cols => new {
        UploadId = savedUpload.Id,
        FullName = cols[0],
        TimesheetWorkDateMonthYear = Convert.ToDateTime(cols[1]),
        TimesheetTaskJobnumber = cols[2],
        TimesheetWorktype = cols[3],
        TimesheetHours = Convert.ToDouble(cols[4]),
        TimesheetOverhead = cols[5]
    })
    .GroupBy(d => new {
        d.FullName,
        d.TimesheetWorkDateMonthYear,
        d.TimesheetTaskJobnumber,
        d.TimesheetWorktype,
        d.TimesheetOverhead
    })
    .Select(g => new UtilisationRow {
        FullName = g.Key.FullName,
        TimesheetWorkDateMonthYear = g.Key.TimesheetWorkDateMonthYear,
        TimesheetTaskJobnumber = g.Key.TimesheetTaskJobnumber,
        TimesheetWorktype = g.Key.TimesheetWorktype,
        TimesheetHours = g.Sum(s => s.TimesheetHours),
        TimesheetOverhead = g.Key.TimesheetOverhead
    })
    .ToList();
```

Now the "pipeline" of your method looks pretty clean:

- The first `Select` does the initial parsing into a temporary record
- `GroupBy` bundles matching records into a group
- The final `Select` produces records of the required type.

Comment: many thanks! Thanks for explaining and helping me continue to learn! :)