# Use string instead of entity class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working in Windows forms application (using Entity Framework) and I have several tables in my database. These tables are similar (they have the same quantity of columns with the same column names), except that they (tables) have different names (it means, I have several entity classes).

On the firstForm (MainForm) I have a listbox, which contains all the table names I have. when the user selects one of them, the new form opens (`addForm`). On this form I have several textboxes to fill the table with data.

My problem is that I want to add data to the tables with universal method using Entity Framework. In general, if I have table called `Customer` with `customerName` and `customerAge` columns (and it corresponding class with the same name) I add data to it like this:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
     var newCustomer = new Customer {customerName = "Alex", customerAge = "24"};
     context.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I don't want to write the code for every table in my database. I think that, when the item will be selected in the listbox, I have to pass the specific class name to constructor and then transform this name (type of string) into the specific class to add data to the specific table associated with this name.

How I can do this?

Another example - `Supplier` table:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
     var newSupplier = new Customer { supplierName = "Bob", supplierAge =  "20" };
     context.Suppliers.Add(newSupplier);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You can get to the object properties using reflection, but how would you automatically identify for each class what the "name" is? And, does every class even have an "age" to fill in, too? In general, though, the answer would be "technically it can be done with reflection, but in practice this is really messy".

Comment: I have this specific situation, where I have the same columns, listbox is filled exactly with the names of tables in my database. you mean, reflection can be used to create get the class from the string?

Comment: No, reflection can be used to get the list of all properties out of a type, get their name, type, attributes etc, and to fill them in dynamically. But there are indeed also ways to instantiate objects from the class name. Are you saying all your tables have identical columns layout? If so, please add  more examples to your question.

Comment: By the way, "I have listbox, which contains all the table names" - how is this list fetched/filled? Are these tables the actual entity classes, or just string names? Because if you have the classes, this all gets a load easier.

Comment: I have names, not classes

Comment: I suggest you look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815454/395685), where I used reflection to fill an object automatically. Specifically, the Reflection stuff is at `typeof(T).GetProperties()`. Though do note it may be tricky to find the property on the context object, since that is a plural, and not all plurals are just "putting an 's' behind the class name". To create objects from class names, look into `CreateInstance(className)` on the `Assembly` class, and/or `Type.GetType(string)`.

Comment: Do note, all of this is _really_ advanced stuff, that breaks a _lot_ of the rules and conventions on how you _should_ be using the programming language. In general, you're _much_ better off just writing a small function or class per type. It'll also run much faster; Reflection is known to be rather slow.

Comment: you mean, that it would be better to write specific methods for every table, yes?

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is pretty advanced stuff, and certainly not how I would handle database classes.

Comment: keep in mind C# is a strongly typed language. If you want to deal with string to a concrete type conversion, other than JSON string deserialization to an object, it would hint at a "code smell". True, you could do reflection to solve this but why would you want to? I'm guessing you have a background in a different language where something like this might be appropriate but not in C# (not as a rule, at least). As @Nyerguds says, using reflection is fairly advanced stuff.

Comment: I think all this [was already done for you before](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=winformgenerator).

Answer (score 1):

If the logic is the same for all items, you could just make use of generics and do something like this:

```
public class Writer<T> where T:class
{
    private DbContext _context;
    public Writer(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Insert(T obj)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You have to provide it with your EF context and specify which type you wish to use.

Hope this helps at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: where can I pass the string I received from listbox in this code?

Comment: @Beginner Inside obj. You would need to create a `Writer<Customer>` and then you can call its `Insert()` method by passing as argument `Customer {supplierName = "Bob", supplierAge = "20"}`.

Comment: yes but first of all I have to create class from the string to paste it in Writer<>, isn't it right?

Comment: stop using strings and build up your object from the fields in the form and pass it down to the writer.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to use the entity object, which is good practice, you could create a dto or similar and use something like AutoMapper to convert between the two objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to accomplish this task:

## Entity classes and context class:

```
public class Person1
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person2
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base ("connection string") { }

    public DbSet<Person1> Person1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person2> Person2 { get; set; }
}
```

Example program, which having database name can add given entity to it using reflection:

```
//I guess you can take this values from controls on your form
string database = "Person1";
int id = 1;
string name = "Charlie";
//get type of an entity
Type entityType = this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name == database).First();
//geet object of an entity class
var entity = Activator.CreateInstance(entityType);
//set properties (name and id)
entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id").SetValue(entity, id);
entity.GetType().GetProperty("Name").SetValue(entity, name);
MyContext ctx = null;
try
{
    ctx = (MyContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyContext));
    //here we'll loop thorugh properties of context (through databases),
    //if name match, add entity using reflection
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in ctx.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.Name == database)
        {
            var dbSet = property.GetValue(ctx);
            //get Add method and invoke it with entity object
            dbSet.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(dbSet, new object[]{ entity });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    //always remeber to call Dispose method!
    if(ctx != null)
        ctx.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` does nothing in the case of `Convert.ChangeType(Activator.CreateInstance(entityType), entityType)`. The value returned by the Activator is already of the appropriate type (and its compile time type is `object`)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 You are correct :) thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` method:

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
}

public class Supplier : Entity
{
}

public void CreateEntity(string TableName, Entity entity)
{
    using(var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var name = new SqlParameter("@name", entity.customerName);
        var age = new SqlParameter("@age", entity.customerAge); 

        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"insert into {TableName} (customerName, customerAge) values (@name, @age)", 
             name, age);
    }
}
```